# opencv fitLine always crashes

Tags: opencv

Hi i try to use fitLine but it always crashes.
I already tried to modify input data (`cv::Mat`, `std::vector<cv::Pointd>`) and output data(`cv::Vect4d`, `std::vector<cv::Pointd>(2)`,  `std::vector<double>(4)`) formats.

Here is my Code:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> points;
// [...] // push_back some (26) points
std::vector<double> line(4,0);
cv::fitLine(points,line,CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01);
```

now it crashes.
Iam using winxp VS2010 with a opencv 2.41 build
I got no call stack and the crash seems to happen in kernel32.dll xstring

Where is my failure?

PS:
i posted the question in the opencv Q&A Forum, but after a look into the question history iam not very confident about a fast solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i underestimated the opencv site:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/14547/fitline-always-crashes/?answer=14550#post-id-14550

The solution is: only float input data is supported.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
// [...] // push_back some (26) points
cv::Vec4f line;
cv::fitLine(points,line,CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01);
```

will work